# What is the input dimension for this keras model?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, classification, keras, sentiment-analysis

I'm doing a tutorial, where I have to evaluate the sentiment of IMDB reviews, positive or negative. 
I first created an index for each word and then replaced every word in each review for each respective index.So now I have a list of lists of reviews, with 18000 reviews but every review has different lengths, what input_shape should I pass to the dense layer? I've tried padding with zeros so all the inputs are of the same length but I can only get 0.5 accuracy everytime.

```
training_reviews = list()
for review in reviews:
    indices = set()
    for word in review.split(" "):
        if(word in word2index.keys()):
            indices.add(word2index[word])

    training_reviews.append(list(indices))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics = ['accuracy'])
```